# Why am I getting errors like these when trying to build my app

Tags: unity, c#, visual-studio, universal-windows

I am currently trying to build and publish my app to the universal windows platform halfway through the process of doing so, during the validation process I got stopped with these errors. The 1st one I am clueless to what I can even do and the second one I don't know why is happening. Please help.

First error:

> **Supported API test**  FAILED
>
> Supported APIs
>
> - **Error Found**: The supported APIs test detected the following errors:
>
>   - API D3D12GetDebugInterface in d3d12.dll is not supported for this application type. UnityPlayer.dll calls this API.
> - **Impact if not fixed:** Using an API that is not part of the Windows SDK for Windows Store apps violates the Windows Store certification requirements.
> - **How to fix:** Review the error messages to identify the API that is not part of the Windows SDK for Windows Store apps. Please note, apps that are built in a debug configuration or without .NET Native enabled (where applicable) can fail this test as these environments may pull in unsupported APIs. Retest your app in a release configuration, and with .NET Native enabled if applicable. See the link below for more information: 
>     Alternatives to Windows APIs in Windows Store apps.

Second error:

> **App resources**  FAILED
>
> Branding
>
> - **Error Found:** The branding validation test encountered the following errors:
>
>   - Image file SplashScreen.scale-200.png is a default image.
> - **Impact if not fixed:** Windows Store apps are expected to be complete and fully functional. Apps using the default images e.g. from templates or SDK samples present a poor user experience and cannot be easily identified in the store catalog.
> - **How to fix:** Replace default images with something more distinct and representative of your app.

Here is the full output for further details:

```
1.1.1.0
App Architecture: x64
Kit Version: 10.0.16299.15
OS Version:  Microsoft Windows 10 Pro (10.0.16299.0)
OS Architecture:  x64

Deployment and launch tests
PASSED
Bytecode generation
PASSED
Background tasks cancelation handler
PASSED
Platform version launch
PASSED
App launch
PASSED
Crashes and hangs
Package compliance test
PASSED
Application count
PASSED
App manifest
PASSED
Bundle manifest
PASSED
Package size
PASSED
Restricted namespace
Windows security features test
PASSED
Binary analyzer
PASSED
Banned file analyzer
PASSED
Private code signing
... (error 1 above)
App manifest resources tests
PASSED
... (error 2 above)
Debug configuration test
PASSED
Debug configuration
File encoding test
PASSED
UTF-8 file encoding
App Capabilities test
PASSED
Special use capabilities
Windows Runtime metadata validation
PASSED
ExclusiveTo attribute
PASSED
Type location
PASSED
Type name case-sensitivity
PASSED
Type name correctness
PASSED
General metadata correctness
PASSED
Properties
Package sanity test
PASSED
Platform appropriate files
PASSED
Supported directory structure check
Resource Usage Test
PASSED
WinJS background task
```

**

[image: These are my errors after the app was tested.]

[image: The second, third and fourth pictures are what my splash setting look like hope it helps]

[image: The second, third and fourth pictures are what my splash setting look like hope it helps]

[image: The second, third and fourth pictures are what my splash setting look like hope it helps]

Comment: So far I have fixed the first problem by setting the build type to Master.

Comment: I fixed the second problem by going into the project assets and changing the splash screen image 200 to an image that was 1240 x 600 and naming it the same thing

Comment: To share a solution to your problem, post it as an Answer, not as a comment. Then you don't need to put "solved" in the title — the Q&A system will see that the question has an answer, and you can mark that answer Accepted.